# SQL UNION is taking number of characters into account when selecting empty string as column

Tags: sql, union

I have two tables that I combine using a UNION ALL. Table1 has 1 column that is not present in table2 and table2 also has 1 column that is not present in table1.

At first I didn't needed the column from table 2 that is not in table1 and I did a SELECT query with `'' as Column1` in the 2nd select. This works just fine.

However, now I want to also retrieve the column that is only present in table2. When I try to do the same as before I end up with only empty values in that column.

Turns out the query is taking the number of characters into account from the first select statement. So when I do `SELECT '  ' as Column2` I end up with the first 2 characters for all the values from table2. This worked the other way around because I got actual values first. But now I need to make the empty column first I'm not sure how to best do this? Of course I can just use a string with 50 spaces or something as the first select, but surely there must be a better way?

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete query you are using as formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, null as col4
from table1 t1
union all
select t2.col1, t2.col2, null as col3, t2.col4
from table2 t2;
```

I recommend using `NULL` rather than `''`, unless you really want an empty string.

Comment: I tried that, however when I do I get a database error. It complaints that the data types must be compatible

Comment: @Chrisvdberge . . . `NULL` should work.  But you can cast the value:  `cast(NULL as XXX)` where `XXX` is the value you want.

Comment: yes I figured as much when I made my previous comment about the need for the types to be compatibel ;)  thx!

Answer (score 0):

Casting the NULL as VARCHAR(50) did the trick.

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, CAST(null as VARCHAR(50)) as col4
from table1 t1
union all
select t2.col1, t2.col2, CAST(null as VARCHAR(50)) as col3, t2.col4
from table2 t2;
```